# Elegantly checking whether a HTTPSession reference is still valid

Tags: java, httpsession

I'm storing all established HTTPSession objects in a hash-map. Is 
there anyway of determining whether a HTTPSession is still valid 
before en-queuing a message?

Example: if I am iterating over the hash- 
map, I only want to enqueue messages for HTTPSession objects that are 
valid.

**UPDATE**

If anyone is interested, I needed this logic with the use of gwt-comet. The solution (as Tomasz Nurkiewicz pointed out) can be found at the bottom [this](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/wiki/GettingStarted) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no explicit API for this. But it is easy to workaround in clean and elegant manner.

Implement [`HttpSessionListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) storing every newly created session in a concurrent map and removing it when session is destroyed. This way your map will always contain only valid sessions. Much cleaner, don't you think?

```
public class SessionStoringListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private Map<String, HttpSession> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession>();

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)
    {
        HttpSession session = httpSessionEvent.getSession();
        sessions.put(session.getId(), session);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent)
    {
        sessions.remove(httpSessionEvent.getSession().getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, there's still a race condition. You still need to handle errors using the session.

Comment: @Yuliy: could you elaborate a little bit more? I must admit I can't find race condition here and I don't know what errors do you mean. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The race is if one thread grabs an HttpSession from the container, while it's getting destroyed by another thread.